# UITableView Unintentionally Selecting Multiple Cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that loads 1 cell per section, to provide spacing.  When tapping on a cell, I can get the cell to appropriately expand.  The problem is that other cells expand as well, and I cannot determine why.  Multiple selection is not implemented.  The GIF will illustrate my problem.  My code is below.

[image: Expands cells that are not selected]

**Code From View Controller**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return searchTextFieldIsEmpty() ? credentials.count : filteredCredentials.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat { return 15 }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return view
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 1 }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CredCell
        cell.delegate = self

        if credentials.isEmpty {
            return cell
        } else {
            tableView.backgroundView = nil
            isFiltering() ? cell.formatCell(filteredCredentials[indexPath.section]) : cell.formatCell(credentials[indexPath.section])
            return cell
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CredCell
        cell.detailsView.isHidden = !cell.detailsView.isHidden

        let borderColor = UIColor(red: 206.0/255.0, green: 214.0/255.0, blue: 234.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        cell.idView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
        cell.notificationView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
        cell.frontImageView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
        cell.backImageView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
        cell.notesView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit With Solution**
@Justin's suggestion was what caused the problem, the state of cell remained while being reused.  I added the following to my custom cell and the problem is solved.

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.detailsView.isHidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you tracking the state of whether the cells been expanded or collapsed and using that in your `cellForRowAt`. My guess is as you scroll up and down it’s reusing cells and sometime’s it re-uses the cell that you’ve expanded so the other cells become expanded as well.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I'm not currently tracking, just hiding and unhiding the detail view.  I'll get on it and let you know.

Comment: That was the issue.  I've edited my question to reflect the code to fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CredCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.detailsView.isHidden = !cell.detailsView.isHidden

        if cell.tag == indexPath.row {
            let borderColor = UIColor(red: 206.0/255.0, green: 214.0/255.0, blue: 234.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
            cell.idView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
            cell.notificationView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
            cell.frontImageView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
            cell.backImageView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
            cell.notesView.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 2, color: borderColor)
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
```

try to use this code, this may help you,
Happy Coding....